# Difference between emission spectrum and diffraction pattern

Tags: education

What is the difference between emission spectrum and diffraction pattern? I known that emission spectrum is the plot of the energy of beams in function of wavelength   when I give energy to a material (--> electrons go up from a low energy level to a high energy level) and then electrons go down from a high energy level to a low energy level.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A diffraction pattern is the result of passing a light beam through a diffraction grating. This is similar to passing a light beam through a prism. It allows you to see the spectrum of the light visualised.

An emission spectrum is a particular kind of spectrum associated with - you guessed it - the emission of photons from atoms.

The two are closely related in the sense that a diffraction pattern - much like the result of passing a beam through a prism - can be used to visually inspect the spectrum of the light. But a diffraction pattern is not tied to any particular source of light (emission, absorption, laser, etc) any more than a prism.

Answer (score 0):

A diffraction pattern is very different from an emission spectrum. Diffraction is a process that occurs when light passes through a medium that has a periodic structure with characteristic length on the order of the wavelength of the light. This causes interference and light which comes out will have a sort of fringed pattern as some points in space experience constructive interference and others destructive interference.

An emission spectrum is what you mentioned, the wavelengths of light which a material is capable of absorbing and emitting due to the microscopic energy modes in the material.

Perhaps these things are linked in your mind due to *refraction*, which is the slowing of light in a medium as a function of its wavelength. If light comes in at an angle to a transparent medium with a refractive index different from the atmosphere, the slowing of light as a function of its wavelength causes the colors in white light to be separated. This is the source of rainbows and the famous [prism picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_of_the_Moon).

Often times, refraction is used to study emissions spectra because it allows you to see which colors (and therefore wavelengths) of light are present in a beam of white light.

Comment: Hi @Bobak Hashemi, thus a diffraction pattern is an image on which there are light regions and dark regions. The light regions represent the points that experience constructive interference, whereas dark regions represent the points that experience destructive interference?

Comment: Hi Gennaro, yes that would be a diffraction pattern